# Gradient of an harmonic function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, harmonic-functions

Let $ M $ be a Riemannian manifold and let $ f $ be an harmonic function on  $ M $.

By Unique continuation theorem we can assert that if  $ \nabla f = 0 $ on an open subset $ \Omega \subset M $ then $ f $ is constant on $ M $.

Now consider a non constant harmonic function $ f $. What can we say about the set of zeros of $ \nabla f $?

By what i say above this set has empty interior surely. Now it is natural to ask if this set has a zero measure. Is it true?

Thanks

Comment: The zero set of  any real-analytic function has measure zero (by considering its Taylor expansion). If $M$ is a real analytic manifold, then $f$ is a real analytic function, and so are its derivatives.